# Unicode writing correctly, reading incorrectly

Tags: python, unicode

I have a .TSV file of movie names and movie data that I am analyzing using the PYDOT package.  the file is linked [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp4gypatb0yuinn/step4.txt).  The file containing the JSON used to create it is linked [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhyw7g2lodcp9xk/step3.txt).

The file is written from parsed JSON, and is written with utf-8 encoding.  Though the file writes correctly, when I read it back in to Python, **the interpreter seems to consistently stop at the following line**:

```
'Taken\t["Liam Neeson", " Maggie Grace", " Jon Gries", " David Warshofsky"]\n'
'The Walking Dead\t["Andrew Lincoln", " Steven Yeun", " Chandler Riggs",'
```

The output should look like this, and is written as such in the file:

```
Taken   ["Liam Neeson", " Maggie Grace", " Jon Gries", " David Warshofsky"]
The Walking Dead    ["Andrew Lincoln", " Steven Yeun", " Chandler Riggs", " Norman Reedus"]
Toy Story 3 ["Tom Hanks", " Tim Allen", " Joan Cusack", " Ned Beatty"]
```

here is the code used to create the text file:

```
step3v2=open('step3.txt', 'rU')
step4=codecs.open('step4.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
data=[]
merged=''
for line in step3v2:
    data.append(json.loads(line))

for row in data:
    moviename=row[u'Title']
    row[u'Actors']=row[u'Actors'].split(',')
    actors=json.dumps(row[u'Actors']) + '\r\n'
    merged+=moviename + '\t'
    merged+=actors
step4.write(merged)
```

Here is the code to read the file:

```
graph=pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph', charset='utf8')
step4v2=open('step4.txt', 'rU')


textfile=step4v2.readlines()
for line in textfile:
    print repr(line)
```

Comment: the interpreter seems to arbritarily stop at the following line: means what? is there an error? or it just waits or?

Comment: No error.  There is more to the string that the interpreter is simply not reading.  I'll edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: and arbitrarily means sometimes? or always?

Comment: Sorry.  Every single time.

Answer (score 1):

```
step4v2=open('step4.txt', 'rU') #this means universal newlines
```

should probably be

```
step4v2=open('step3.txt', 'rb') #this means read the binary data
```

using the file on dropbox you linked

```
>>> f =open (os.path.expanduser("~\\Downloads\\step4.txt"),"rb")
>>> for line in f: print repr(line)
```

worked fine it seemed

Comment: Just restarted my machine to make sure.  I'm still receiving the same "error".  Furthermore, if I try to ast.literal_eval() that part of the string, I receive an error message back

Comment: umm of coarse... `step4.txt` is not valid python ... why would you ast.literal_Eval it?  hmmm if you download the file from the dropbox do the two lines above print all movies?

Comment: I was splitting the string by '\t', then ast.literal_eval()ing the 'list' portion of the string.  When I download the file from dropbox, it works perfectly, but when I read the file that scripts writes locally, the error persists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47205/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-mike)

Comment: Found the issue.  I placed my step4.close() statement before I read the file back in to memory.  worked like a charm.  Thank you for the elp, and sorry for the rookie mistake.